# animate height of a dropdown with 60fps

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I realized that animating height is an expensive operation. Even on high end computers (MacBook Pro), animating height often causes jagged animation.

Sample code:

```js
document.querySelector("#title").addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (document.querySelector("#wrapper").style.height != "60px") {
    document.querySelector("#wrapper").style.height = "60px";
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#wrapper").style.height = "20px";
  }
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 20px;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="title">Title</div>
  <div>
    <div class="item">Dropdown Label 1</div>
    <div class="item">Dropdown Label 2</div>
  </div>

</div>
<div>Other stuff</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dy1o4a3c/1/

What is the alternative? I use css `transform` property to achieve 60fps animations, but I do not know how to use it to animate height of a dropdown.

Edit: Apparently if dev tools are open, the effect is magnified.

Comment: use `steps` animation with 60 steps per 1 second animation duration.

Comment: This is perfectly smooth in Safari (even on a scaled external monitor).